# How do I prevent Spring Boot AOP from removing type annotations?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-aop

I am pretty new to Spring Boot and its flavor of AOP, but not new to programming in other languages and AOP frameworks. This one challenge I am not sure how to solve.

I have a simple metadata decorator:

```
@Target(ElementType.TYPE)
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface GreetingsMeta {
    public float version() default 0;
    public String name() default "";
}
```

It works just fine with dependency injection:

```
public GreetingController(List<IGreetingService> greetings) throws Exception {
    this.greetings = new HashMap<>();
    greetings.forEach(m -> {
        Class<?> clazz = m.getClass();
        if (clazz.isAnnotationPresent(GreetingsMeta.class)) {
            GreetingsMeta[] s = clazz.getAnnotationsByType(GreetingsMeta.class);
            this.greetings.put(s[0].name(), m);
        }
    });
}
```

Until I applied a standard logging aspect:

```
@Aspect
@Component
public class LoggingAspect {
    @Around("execution(* com.firm..*(..)))")
    public Object profileAllMethods(ProceedingJoinPoint joinPoint) throws Throwable {
        MethodSignature methodSignature = (MethodSignature) joinPoint.getSignature();
        String methodName = methodSignature.getName();
        final StopWatch stopWatch = new StopWatch();
        stopWatch.start();
        Object result = joinPoint.proceed();
        stopWatch.stop();
        LogManager.getLogger(methodSignature.getDeclaringType())
        .info(methodName + " " + (stopWatch.getTotalTimeSeconds() * 1000) + " µs");
        return result;
    }
}
```

Then the list of annotationsData becomes empty, even the @Component annotation is gone.

Sample meta-decorated class:

```
@Component
@GreetingsMeta(name = "Default", version = 1.0f)
public class DefaultGreetingsService implements IGreetingService {


    @Override
    public String message(String content) {
        return "Hello, " + content;
    }
}
```

How should I troubleshoot?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may want to look into [AnnotationUtils](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/core/annotation/AnnotationUtils.html)

```java
Method method = methodSignature.getMethod();
GreetingsMeta greetingsMeta = AnnotationUtils.findAnnotation(method, GreetingsMeta.class);
```

Answer (score 2):

> How do I prevent Spring Boot AOP from removing type annotations?

Spring Boot does not remove anything, but for Spring AOP is uses dynamic proxies generated during runtime, i.e. subclasses or interface implementations with event hooks (joinpoints) for aspect advice code wired in via pointcuts. By default, annotations are not inherited, so this is just a JVM feature.

There is one exception for subclasses inheriting annotations from parent classes: You can add the meta annotation [`@Inherited`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/annotation/Inherited.html) to your own annotation class `GreetingsMeta`. The effect will be that if you annotate any class with it, all subclasses (also dynamic proxies created by Spring AOP) will inherit the annotation and your original code should run as expected.

So in this case there is no need to use `AnnotationUtils` as suggested by *JC Carrillo*. His approach works too, of course. It is just more complicated because `AnnotationUtils` uses a lot of reflection magic and lots of helper classes internally in order to compute results. Thus, I would only use `AnnotationUtils` in cases where you don't directly annotate a class but e.g. methods or interfaces because `@Inherited` has no effect on them as documented. Or if you rely on a hierarchy of Spring (or own) meta annotations (annotations on annotations) and you need to get information from them all merged into one, `AnnotationUtils` or `MergedAnnotations` are appropriate.